# "Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException" compile time error: What exactly is it for?

Tags: java, exception

Consider the following snippet of an unfinished method:

```
private void synchronize(TreeItem<String> treeItem, Path newDir) {
    for (TreeItem<String> i : treeItem.getChildren()) {
        if (i.getGraphic().equals(GREEN_DOT)) {
            copyFile(new File(i.getValue()), newDir.toFile(), DEFAULT_COPY_BUFFER_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

In my project, the copyFile() call is underlined and the IDE displays the error described above. I understand what an exception is, but what I'm not so sure about is why does this particular error needs to be fixed by adding "throws IOException" into the method signature. Why does it need to be there; isn't throwing the exception within the implementation of copyFile() enough? What is the utility gained by typing that little formula into the method signature, an propagating it like that into any method that calls another method with it already written in?

Comment: Sounds like you should read the Java exceptions tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html Note as you go along that `IOException` is a *checked exception*.

Comment: If you're throwing the exception in copyFile(), then its basically telling you that you have to handle that exception when you call that method, you could put the method call within a try / catch clause.

Comment: You should never use `throws`. You should catch an exception, and at least print the stack trace.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi There are many valid use cases for exposing a checked exception - catching an exception & swallowing it is often the worst thing you can do.

Comment: @thecoop Does printing the stack trace mean swallowing the exception? It will certainly expose the exception.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi but the program will continue running, in a probably invalid state, causing non-obvious causal problems elsewhere. And the println will probably go to a log file, or disappear, or something else where it will be ignored. Throwing an exception forces the caller to deal with it then and there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare that your method can throw `IOException`s, so that calling code knows that it may come up. The methods called within your method declare `throws IOException`, so the compiler knows that an `IOException` may be thrown within them and interrupt your method, and therefore you must also declare that you can throw `IOException` as your method can also interrupt calling code. The other way to stop the error is to actually catch the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Java language specification demands it.
The reason could be for better documentation built in, or that the programmer will always remember to deal with these exception.

As you know this is not mandatory as other languages don't require this kind of declaration, but Java does.

Answer (score -2):

Nope , all methods to work with files need to throws IOexception.

Comment: That's not quite correct. `throws IOException` is *one* way to deal with it, but definitely not the only one. One can also catch and handle it.

Comment: ok , i mean u can surround with try catch , and catch the IOexception.